# extract unique values and make a new dataframe on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

Assume this is my sample input `df`:

```
     date       h_league
0  19901126        AA
1  19911127        NA
2  20030130        AA
3  20041217       NaN
4  20080716        AA
5  20011215        NA
6  19970603       NaN
```

I'm looking to extract unique leagues from `h_league` and also make new two cols one is `max_date` and has maximum date and `min_date` that has minimum date for the league.

```
# Desired Output:

  h_league   Max_date    Min_date
0    AA      20080716    19901126
1    NA      20011215    19911127
```

I had to write a function for this task that returns similar output that I desire but not the exact desired output.

```
def league_info(league):
    league_games = df[df["h_league"] == league]
    earliest = df["date"].min()
    latest = df["date"].max()
    print("{} went from {} to {}".format(league,earliest,latest))

for league in df["h_league"].unique():
    league_info(league)
```

I'm looking for a pandas way to achieve my desired output. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=df.fillna('NA')
df.groupby('h_league').date.agg(['max','min'])
Out[98]: 
               max       min
h_league                    
AA        20080716  19901126
NA        20041217  19911127
```

Comment: Is there a way I could rename those column names?

Comment: @SaiKumar `newdf=df.groupby('h_league').date.agg(['max','min']);
newdf.columns=['yourname1','yourname2']`

Answer (score 1):

```
df2=df.fillna('NA')  
df2.groupby('h_league').date.agg(['max','min'])
```

Does this work for you? You can assign `df=df.fillna('NA')` too. let me know if this works. I tried it.

Comment: You can do the renaming this way in the same statement. I just saw the other question. df2.groupby('h_league').date.agg(['max','min']).reset_index().rename(columns={'max':'x','min' : 'y'})